# Wordpress - the_title() limit character in standard widget

Tags: wordpress

I copy standard Recent Post widget to function.php, I unregister it and register my new class. In widget I see this function that is responsible for showing title of recent posts in A tag:

```
<?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php  if ( get_the_title() ) {
                    $t = the_title();
                    $t = substr($t, 0, 40); /// this doesn't work

                }else{
                    the_ID();
                }
                ?>
            </a>
...
...
```

But this substr doesn't work - title is always display all. What I do wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `$t = the_title();` with `$t = get_the_title();`. `the_title()` echos the title to the screen and doesn't return anything

Comment: Yes, dragos.bd answer earlier - the_title "has echo on" so this also works - the_title('', '', false);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alsp use [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.mb-substr.php), It works almost the same way as [substr](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.substr.php) but the difference is that you can add a new parameter to specify the encoding type, whether is UTF-8 or a different encoding.

Try this:

```
$t =  mb_substr($t, 0, 40, 'UTF-8');
```

LATER EDIT: change

```
 $t = the_title();
```

with

```
$t = get_the_title();
```

You are using the_title instead of get_the_title to give it to an specific variable. And be sure to echo $t after all of this.

Comment: Are you sure you echo $t after substr ?

Comment: yes, with echo also nothing change ... it's something with widget ,not with substr

Comment: I'm in the loop - php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post();

Comment: ok I change it to get_the_title and it works ... why? I'm new in wordpress. Where is the different?

Comment: because the_title print the result directly and you cant give it to an specific variable. Read [the_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) wp codex

Comment: I do not see different in descriptions of the_title and get_the_title - only different is that get_the_title can be used outside of loop. Nothing about "direct print"

Comment: ok now I get it ... this just work like this. I can also set - the_title('', '', false); and it will also work because I set echo to false.

Comment: Ok, more explicit: if you have a post title like "Bla bla title" use this: the_title(); the result is "Bla bla title" without any echo or print neded to be write by yourself, that mean this is directly write the title not give it to an variable, $t=the_title(); doesnt work. And if you use get_the_title you can add this to an specific variable like: $t=get_the_title(); echo $t;

Answer (score 3):

this one should work

```
echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 40, '...');
```

Comment: Try posting answer to new questions. This one already has an accepted answer.